# how to Write xml text in Xml File after specific node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-namespaces

well i have an following xml file :

```
 <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT FirstName,Lastname FROM Person</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="FirstName">
          <DataField>FirstName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Lastname">
          <DataField>Lastname</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
     </Fields>
```

wat i have to do is,i have to write xml text from node "fields" to "/fields" after node "query"..how to do this..plz help me

Comment: :Can you describe what you really want to achieve? " xml text from node "fields" to "/fields" after node "query". Describe your scenario well so that your problem gets solve

Comment: well i have xml file is :<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
   <buttons>   
      <workshop1>hello</workshop1>  
    <workshop1>Google</workshop1>  
      <url1>www.google.co.uk</url1> 
    </buttons>
</Reports> and i have to add above xml file in this xml file after </buttons> node..how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xdocument to manupulate xml. You can refer following snippet to add element into  tag. Hope this helps

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01";
         XNamespace ns1 = "schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting";


         xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "Fields").Add(new XElement("Field", new XAttribute("Name","ReportId"), new XElement(ns1 + "TypeName", "System.Int64"), new XElement("DataField", "ReportId")));


xdoc.Save(test.xml");
```

Adding namespace is important here. I have attached source and result file also for your reference.

Source File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01" xmlns:rd="schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>SELECT FirstName,Lastname FROM Person</CommandText>
  </Query>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="FirstName">
      <DataField>FirstName</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Lastname">
      <DataField>Lastname</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</Report>
```

Result file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01" xmlns:rd="schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>SELECT FirstName,Lastname FROM Person</CommandText>
  </Query>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="FirstName">
      <DataField>FirstName</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Lastname">
      <DataField>Lastname</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="ReportId" xmlns="">
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName>
      <DataField>ReportId</DataField>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
</Report>
```

Comment: @Roshan04 are you merging two xml files?

Comment: well it gives error that rd: is undeclared prefix..no m not merging two xml file.I change my code as per your suggestion

Comment: @Roshan04 You have to specify namespace like XNamespace ns = "schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01";

Comment: m trying to add :<Fields><Field Name=\"ReportId\"><DataField>ReportId</DataField><rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName></Field> before <Fields>

Comment: yes i have aded that namesapce ,but still it gives error

Comment: @Roshan04 I have updated my answer. check now with updated one. Are question main pura explain ker bhai kya kerna hai who...

Comment: Getting Error: NullReferenceException at new XElement